# Getting the filename/path from MvvmCross Plugins.DownloadCache

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm currently using MvvmCross DownloadCache -- and it's working alright -- especially nice when I just need to drop in an Image URL and it automagically downloads / caches the image and serves up a UIImage.

I was hoping to leverage the code for one other use case -- which is I'd like to grab source images from URL's and cache the files on the local file system, but what I really want for this other use case is the image path on the local file system instead of the UIImage itself.

What would help me most if I could get an example of how I might accomplish that.  Is it possible to make that happen in a PCL, or does it need to go into the platform specific code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source for the plugin, you'll find https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.2/Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache/IMvxFileDownloadCache.cs - that will give you a local file path for a cached file:

```
public interface IMvxFileDownloadCache 
{ 
     void RequestLocalFilePath(string httpSource, Action<string> success, Action<Exception> error); 
}
```

You can get hold of a service implementing this interface using `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileDownloadCache>()`

To then convert that into a system-wide file path, try `NativePath` in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.2/Plugins/Cirrious/File/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File/IMvxFileStore.cs#L27

Comment: can you take a look at my question below?  It's very much related to your answer, so didn't want to start a new SO question...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks -- that works, but just in case anyone else is following along, I wanted to document how I got the `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileDownloadCache>()` to work.  In my setup.cs (in the touch project), I had:

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance ()
{
    Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
    Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
    Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
    ...
}
```

But that wasn't enough, because nothing actually registers `IMvxFileDownloadCache` inside the DownloadCache plugin (which I was expecting, but it's just not the case).

So then I tried adding this line here:

```
Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IMvxFileDownloadCache, MvxFileDownloadCache>();
```

But that failed because MvxFileDownloadCache constructor takes a few arguments.  So I ended up with this:

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance ()
{

    ...

    var configuration = MvxDownloadCacheConfiguration.Default;

    var fileDownloadCache = new MvxFileDownloadCache(
        configuration.CacheName,
        configuration.CacheFolderPath,
        configuration.MaxFiles,
        configuration.MaxFileAge);

    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxFileDownloadCache>(fileDownloadCache);

    ...
}
```

And the resolve works okay now.

**Question:**
I do wonder what happens if two MvxFileDownloadCache objects that are configured in exactly the same way will cause issues by stepping on each other.  I could avoid that question by changing the cache name on the one I'm constructing by hand, but I do want it to be a single cache (the assets will be the same).

Comment: I thought DownloadCache plugin had a bug until I saw your answer. Thanks